# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable when using lists

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to get it so that if the user enters something from the list, it will print the message. However, I'm met with a

> "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable".

```
li = "One,Two,Three,Four"
a,b,c,d = li.split(",")
number = input("Enter Number")

if input == li(a,b,c,d):
    print("Message")
```

Comment: From which list?

Comment: What I'd like to know is where you got the idea to do `input == li(a,b,c,d)`. What is `li(a,b,c,d)` supposed to mean? What did you expect that to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if an object is one of the elements of a list, you need to use the `in` operator, not the `==` operator:

```
if number in (a,b,c,d):
    # Here^
    print("Message")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to define the entries together just to separate them later; also you can directly check if an entry is in your list:

```
entries = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
number = input("Enter Number: ")
if number in entries:
    print("Message")
```

For large datasets consider using a `set` instead of a list for entries.